# To implement rules in firebase database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How do i implement security rules to my firebase database using Node JS
I tried various options....

i wrote rule as follows

---

```
{
 "rules": {
  "data":{
     ".read": "auth.uid == 'my auth.uid'",
    ".write": "auth.uid == 'my auth.uid'"
       }
    } 
}
```

---

and in my Nodejs code :

```
 var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
 var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("my firebase Secrete key");
 var auth = tokenGenerator.createToken(
     { "provider": "anonymous", "uid": "my auth.uid" },
     {admin: true}
 );
```

Please help me I m new..

Comment: It looks like you're using some outdated documentation -- I'd recommend taking a look [at the Server Auth guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/) and go from there.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thanks